# How to add font-awesome to JsFiddle

Tags: jsfiddle, font-awesome

JsFiddle is my laboratory but everything is at a halt at the moment because I cant get font-awesome to work in it. I tried using the space provided for external links but to no avail. I even added the link directly and it still didn't work.

I'm in the middle of an experiment and I'm not able to get it working. What is the correct way to add font-awesome to JsFiddle?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just paste the href part of the CDN link

```
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

to External Resourses (on the left hand side panel) and click the plus sign.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karin/804jeg82/1/) for example.

Answer (score 6):

Check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/leolanese/JfGVE/) out. It is using an cdn URL in the CSS area.

```
@font-face{
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    src:url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/font//fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix)
```

Answer (score 4):

Import [this script](https://use.fontawesome.com/c3ef28c600.js):

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c3ef28c600.js"></script>
```

or

```
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f83feeae10.js" ></script>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/od88gyh9/2)

Answer (score 4):

Font Awesome 5

`https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css`

On the left sidebar of JSFiddle **click Resources** to open an input field.

**Paste** the above link into it.

**Click** the **X** button to add it to your fiddle.

For current versions and other options (free/pro versions etc) visit their info page on how to [Use Font Awesome's Free CDN](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css)